# SSIS Script Task WebRequest Requiring TLS

Tags: ssis

We have a SSIS Script Task calling a json web service deployed to a SQL Server 2012 SSIS catalog that has worked fine for months. After installing assorted server updates (Windows and SQL Server) it stopped working. After a lot of digging we found that the error thrown was;

> The request was aborted: Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel.

We already have the following line in our code to set TLS properly and it has worked fine for quite some time now.

```
System.Net.ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After 2 days of digging, we finally came across the solution on [social.technet.microsoft.com](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/ie/en-US/7f5502cc-a8ca-468d-ad55-a402376f2d42/question-on-setting-a-tls-12-value-within-a-ssis-package-when-connecting-to-vendors-url-using-a?forum=sqlintegrationservices).

In short, the solution was to add a couple of registry keys to the server;

```
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\.NETFramework\v4.0.30319]
"SchUseStrongCrypto"=dword:00000001

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\Microsoft\.NETFramework\v4.0.30319]
"SchUseStrongCrypto"=dword:00000001
```

Hopefully, this will save someone else the time we wasted trying to figure this out...

Comment: Thanks, I really appreciate the solution. It saved me a lot of time.